# D3 - stack function bar chart filter

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a codepen here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WdWyem?editors=1010

I have a simple stacked bar chart with a legend

I'm trying to use the legend to filter the bar chart.

When I click the colored block in the legend I'd like to remove that bar from the chart.

I have some basic data and I'm using D3's stack to create the stackedSeries and passing in the keys from an array 'keys'

I'm using the same 'keys' to create the legend and adding a class to each block that is the name of the key

When the block is clicked I wanted to capture the key name and remove it from the keys array and run the stack function again and redraw the chart.

This isn't working and I can't see how I can change the keys array and re-run the stack and

I haven't thought about getting the bars back yet.

```
stack = d3.stack()
    .keys(getKeys());

function getKeys() {
    console.log(keys)
    return keys
}

function createStack() {
    console.log('here');
    stackedSeries = stack(dataToStack);
}

createStack();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redraw the chart you need to recreate `stack`, so just move your `stack` creation into `createStack` function:

```
function createStack() {
    stack = d3.stack()
        .keys(getKeys());
    console.log('here');
    stackedSeries = stack(dataToStack);
}
```

Also you have to add the logic related to the colors of bars. For example you can change the `colors` array dynamically like you change the `keys` array

Comment: I had tried this but whichever block is clicked it will remove the top section of each bar and not the correct section

Comment: I think you are confused by wrong colors. Check this [sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XVQwgj?editors=1010) pls. I just moved `stack` creation and added `colors` array changing: `colors.splice(index, 1);`

Comment: Sorry I'd missed the `color.splice(index, 1)`. Can you explain how this works. I can see its removing the color but I can't see why that makes it work

Comment: Lets assume we are not changing colors array. In `drawChart` function we are iterating through every layer (section) and assignig the color from the `colors` array: 1) light blue - for `usedInf` 2) dark blue - for `newInf` 3) yellow - for `totalInf`. When you delete the second layer, then you are iterating again throug every layer and for two layers you are getting first two color: 1) ligth blue - for `usedInf` 2) dark blue - for `totalInf`. That's why we need to change `color` array to get right colors.